# Supscription in canload guard Angular2+

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, guard

I'm trying to use combineLatest in canload guard but it gets me this error: Type **'Subscription' is missing the following properties from type 'Observable': _isScalar, source, operator, lift, and 6 more.**

my code looks like:

```
canLoad(route: Route): Observable<boolean> {
        return combineLatest(this.router.events, this.resources$, this.role$)
            .subscribe(([nav, res, role]) => {
              // some logic
                return false;
            })
 }
```

I want to listen route event and check permissions by route slug. Can someone help me?

Comment: Lievno is right, you need to return Observable, not Subscription.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have to `subscribe` just return `combineLatest`.

The method except a `Observable` but you return a `Subscription`.

```
canLoad(route: Route): Observable<boolean> {
        return combineLatest(this.router.events, this.resources$, this.role$)
               .pipe(
                   // take the first value emitted and complete
                   first()
                   map((value) => {
                       if(value) {
                           return true;
                       }
                       return false;
                   })
               )
}
```

Comment: I tried it but there is another problem, the module doesn't load. I use lazy loading

Comment: in app route I have: `{
      path: 'campaigns',
      canLoad: [PermissionGuard],
      loadChildren: () => import('@pages/campaign-page/campaign-page.module').then(m => m.CampaignPageModule)
    },`

Comment: But it only happens when canLoad return observable, If I return just True or False it works fine

Comment: Have you returned a boolean after your logic part with the observable and are sure your observable is completed?

Comment: I found solution with first() operator after map